# UIL - ImageAware is reused for another image. Task is cancelled

Tags: android, android-listview, universal-image-loader

First, I have a adapter which uses the [Universal Image Loader](https://github.com/nostra13/Android-Universal-Image-Loader) library to get thumbnail for each item. It looks like this:

```
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
 ViewHolder viewHolder;
    if (convertView == null) {
        convertView = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.page_edit_item, null);
        viewHolder = new ViewHolder();
        viewHolder.thumbnailImageView= (ImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.imgPageData);
                 viewHolder.progressBar =(ProgressBar) convertView.findViewById(R.id.photo_upload_progress_view);
        convertView.setTag(viewHolder);
    } else {
        viewHolder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
    }

     viewHolder.progressBar.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
     String photoPath = getItem(position).getPhoto();
     ImageLoader.getInstance().displayImage(photoPath, viewHolder.thumbnailImageView, new SimpleImageLoadingListener(){
            @Override
            public void onLoadingComplete(String imageUri, View view, Bitmap loadedImage) {
                progressBar.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            }
        });
}
```

When tap on listview item, it moves to the detail screen activity. In this screen, I try to get the detail image (has the same image url with selected item).

```
     ImageLoader.getInstance().displayImage(photoPath, detailImageView);
```

The problem is when I select an item that downloaded image (it is loaded and displayed in listview), but the detail screen doesn't show this image immediately, it still black and wait for all items in adapter listview complete loaded and displayed, then it can display.
From the logcat I can see this line when go to detail screen:

```
ImageAware is reused for another image. Task is cancelled
```

Is there any idea?

**Update**: here is my UIL config

```
  DisplayImageOptions options = new DisplayImageOptions.Builder()
            .resetViewBeforeLoading(true)
            .cacheInMemory(true)
            .cacheOnDisc(true)
            .bitmapConfig(Bitmap.Config.RGB_565) // default
            .displayer(new SimpleBitmapDisplayer())
            .build();
    ImageLoaderConfiguration config = new ImageLoaderConfiguration.Builder(getApplicationContext())
            .memoryCacheExtraOptions(1024, 768)
            .discCacheExtraOptions(1024, 768, CompressFormat.JPEG, 75, null)
            .taskExecutor(getThreadPool())
            .taskExecutorForCachedImages(getThreadPool())
            .memoryCache(new UsingFreqLimitedMemoryCache(2 * 1024 * 1024)) // default
            .discCache(new LimitedAgeDiscCache(cacheDir, 3600 * 24 * 7)) // default
            .discCacheFileNameGenerator(new HashCodeFileNameGenerator()) // default
            .imageDownloader(new BaseImageDownloader(getApplicationContext())) // default
            .defaultDisplayImageOptions(options) // default
            .denyCacheImageMultipleSizesInMemory()
            .writeDebugLogs()
            .build();
    ImageLoader.getInstance().init(config);
```

Comment: have you got any solution for this issue?

Comment: no, and I quit this project. As I remember, I replaced UIL by this one: https://github.com/yangfuhai/afinal

Answer (score 4):

I have encountered this problem also.  After search and try many times, I still could not find a reason. Occasionally, I thought the problem may be due to layout, so I checked it:

```
<ListView
        android:id="@+id/listView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

</ListView>
```

then I change listView's layout_height from "wrap_content" to "match_parent", question resolved!

```
<ListView
        android:id="@+id/listView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

</ListView>
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm new to this library, but I think the problem is this line:

```
ImageLoaderConfiguration config.denyCacheImageMultipleSizesInMemory()
```

I believe that ensures that for each image uri there will only be one size cached in memory. So the detail version has to be loaded all over again.

Also, do you cancel the remaining thumbnail tasks/loads once the detail view is called? If not, then those are still on the stack.

Edit: Some API details are outdated, but you can check the Configuration doc -http://www.intexsoft.com/blog/item/72-universal-image-loader-part-2.html

Answer (score 0):

The message in the log refers to the list view images. The reason your detail page image takes longer to load could be related to the delay set in the DisplayImageOptions

```
.delayBeforeLoading(1000)
```

Are you using the the default Configuration?

Comment: I don't set the delay for option. Please take a look my updated question.

Comment: Have you tried adding .delayBeforeLoading(0) to the DisplayImageOptions?

Comment: Could you provide the adapter code that loads the detail listview?

Answer (score 0):

If you dont want imageLoader to reuse another image then use "resetViewBeforeLoading(true)"

```
   DisplayImageOptions defaultOptions;

   defaultOptions = new DisplayImageOptions.Builder()
                .resetViewBeforeLoading(true)
                .displayer(new FadeInBitmapDisplayer(700))
                .cacheOnDisk(true)
                .cacheInMemory(true)
                .bitmapConfig(Bitmap.Config.RGB_565)
                .build();
```

now it will not show another random image before your actual image loads.

src:- from my own experience